# How to make a screen inactive with opacity?

Tags: flutter

Ive a menu that pops up(halfway up the screen) from a bottom navigation bar. It overlays a screen. How do I make that screen inactive. I don't want to use a `bootomsheet` because I want the bottom navigation bar to remain in view at all times. I think I need to use the modal barrier widget but not sure how to implement. An example would be great!

Comment: So you want to disable all the events in non overlapped area, don't you?

Comment: yep that's exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

[AbsorbPointer](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AbsorbPointer-class.html) is exactly what you want, just put it at the topmost in the widget subtree you'd like to block, here is the referenced [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65HoWqBboI8) (Flutter Widget of the Week)

Comment: thanks Ill have a look later and upvote if it works. I need opacity as well but should be able to incorporate that.